# Carrierwave File Upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am trying multiple file upload proposed by railcasts.com Jquery File Upload. I have followed the test, however it seem that everytime i refresh the server, nothing gets seen and in the following browser i get this

- google: blank icons
- firefox: text "/assets/

Nothing seem to be uploaded in my folder. Where I would like my picture to be uploader would be public/upload/:imageid

Here my code
Uploader

```
class AimageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.id}"
  end
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end   
end
```

View

```
<div><%= image_tag(ad.aimage_url(:thumb)) %></div>
```

Did i miss a step?

Model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: ads
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  name             :string(255)
#  aimage           :string(255)
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  advertisement_id :integer
#

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :aimage, :advertisement_id, :name
  mount_uploader :aimage, AimageUploader
end
```

View index.html.erb

```
<% @ads.each do |ad| %>
  <div><%= ad.name %></div>
  <%= image_tag(ad.aimage_url(:thumb)) if ad.aimage? %>
  <div>
    <%= link_to 'Show', ad %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ad_path(ad) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', ad, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<br />

<%= form_for Ad.new do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :aimage, "Upload advertisement:" %></div>
  <div><%= f.file_field :aimage, multiple: true, name: "advertisement[aimage]" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @ads = Ad.all
  end
  def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @ad = Ad.new
  end
  def edit
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
  end
  def create
    @ad = Ad.create(params[:ad])
    if @ad.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created advertisement."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def destroy
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    @ad.destroy
  end
end
```

Javascript ads.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_ad').fileupload()
```

To me looks all good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your uploader mounted to your model? If not, try this

```
mount_uploader :image, AimageUploader
```

and also, in your view, set the multiple option

```
<%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "model_name[image]" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

Create a model called Image as follows:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file
end
```

Let assume User model will have multiple images:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

You can have separate image_controller to handle your file upload

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The thing with paperclip is it doesn't allow multiple file upload, hence i change to carrierwave

Comment: You can use simple JQuery to make allow multiple file upload.

Comment: That what i am doing, but its not working, it doesn't upload the file, it does create two or tree 'item' but the image don't get uploaded to my folder

Comment: I am suggesting you to use combination of paperclip+JQuery to get multiple file upload. If you share your model details I can write code for you.